# Efficent reflection in the loop

Tags: c#, reflection

I have performance problems when using reflection in the loops. The thing is I am using it to repeatedly access objects at the end of the long dependency chains. For example, in a situation like that

```
class FirstObject 
{
    public SecondObject sO;
}

class SecondObject
{
    public ThirdObject tO;
}

class ThirdObject
{
    public FourthObject fO;
}

class FourthObject
{
    public object neededValue;
}
```

Since I am interested only in a value contained by the last object, I need to repeatedly travel through the whole chain with `GetProperty().GetValue()`

FirstObject -> SecondObject -> ThirdObject -> FourthObject [neededValue]

Is there any way, perhaps some API, which could be used to shorten chains or to just save the whole path to `neededValue` in this situations?

### Clarification

I need to do this with list containing FirstObjects. I cannot rewrite code to reduce level of nesting: It is generated automatically.

Comment: Can you give us a look at the code you're *currently* using? There are a few ways to optimise it (caching and generating IL come to mind), but we'd need to see how you're doing it at present.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite your code so you don't need reflection, or reduce the object nesting.

Comment: The title is tricky.. This is called nested objects and not loops.

Comment: Just to make things clear. Do you have a Collection of `FirstObject` objects and you want to get the values of `neededValue` through reflection ? Is that the case ?

Comment: You could write a Reflection based XPath implementation. That might be a bit of work initially but would certainly be easy to use. Why exactly do you need to use Relfection? Your example code doesn't tell us why you want/need to do this.

Comment: It seems like a linked list without implement an interface, and you use Reflection as a workaround to traverse it

Comment: It's not quite clear why and how do you use reflection inside a loop. Please provide a concrete example (a.k.a. [mcve])

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick you can use instead of reflection's `GetValue()`. It is definitely faster, but the code readability will be much worse.

```
object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    MethodInfo propertyGetter = obj.GetType().GetMethod("get_" + propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
    Func<object> getPropertyValue = (Func<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), obj, propertyGetter);
    return getPropertyValue();
}
```

Here we're using a little "hack" knowing that a property getter is just a method that has a predefined name: `get_<PropertyName>()`.

You can even cache the `propertyGetter` object from the above example and reuse it, if your objects hierarchy is the same each time.

---

### UPDATE

You can even create a delegate for the property getter without a concrete object reference. So you can use this delegate with many objects (of the same type):

```
Func<ObjectType, object> getPropertyValue = (Func<ObjectType, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ObjectType, object>), propertyGetter);

ObjectType obj;
var propertyValue = getPropertyValue(obj);
```

If you cache the `getPropertyValue()` delegate, then the performance will be significant better than a call to the `GetValue()` method.

Comment: This is using reflection - the `GetMethod` in particular (assuming also you meant `obj.GetType()`)

Comment: @Rob right, but this doesn't use the slow `GetValue()` method. Thanks for the hint about `GetType()`.

Comment: You actually **should** cache MethodInfo objects as they tend to take a lot of execution time.

Comment: @Migol, I have benchmarked it. With a 100.000 for-loop, the cached version runs 218 ms, the uncached one 227 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the type of the root object and the path to the member you are interested in, you can prepare a `Func<object, object>` delegate outside of the loop and use it inside. This way you'll eliminate both `GetProperty` / `GetField` and `GetValue` reflection costs.

The easiest way of preparing such delegate is to build and compile lambda expression using `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` methods:

```
public static class SelectorFactory
{    
    public static Func<object, object> GetSelector(Type type, string memberPath)
    {
        return CreateSelector(type, memberPath);
    }

    static Func<object, object> CreateSelector(Type type, string memberPath)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "source");
        var source = Expression.Convert(parameter, type);
        var value = memberPath.Split('.').Aggregate(
            (Expression)source, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        if (value.Type.IsValueType)
            value = Expression.Convert(value, typeof(object));
        // (object source) => (object)((T)source).Prop1.Prop2...PropN
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(value, parameter);
        return selector.Compile();
    }
}
```

Test with your example:

```
// This would be outside of the loop
var selector = SelectorFactory.GetSelector(typeof(FirstObject), "sO.tO.fO.neededValue");
// and this inside (of course instead of new you would get item from a list)
var item = new FirstObject { sO = new SecondObject { tO = new ThirdObject { fO = new FourthObject { neededValue = "Ivan" } } } };
var value = selector(item);
```

P.S. If you wonder why I've used two helper methods (one public and one private), it's because at some point you can easily add selector caching, for instance adding a dictionary and changing just the public method implementation like this:

```
static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Func<object, object>> selectorCache = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Func<object, object>>();

public static Func<object, object> GetSelector(Type type, string memberPath)
{
    var key = Tuple.Create(type, memberPath);
    Func<object, object> value;
    lock (selectorCache)
    {
        if (!selectorCache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            selectorCache.Add(key, value = CreateSelector(type, memberPath));
    }
    return value;
}
```